# Why this code for Linked List is showing error in HackerRank?

Tags: python, data-structures, linked-list

I have implemented the linked list with this code in IDLE. If I traverse it shows the expected output. But in hackerrank I'm in trouble. What am I missing?
Here is the problem [link](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/insert-a-node-at-the-tail-of-a-linked-list/problem)

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self,data=None,next_node = None):
        self.data = data
        self.next_node = next_node

    def get_data(self):
        return self.data
    def get_next(self):
        return self.next_node
    def set_next(self,new_next):
        self.next_node = new_next
class LL:
    def __init__(self,head=None,tail=None):
       self.head = head   #head
       self.tail = tail   #tail
    def Insert(self,data):
        new_node =  Node(data) #new_node
        new_node.set_next(None)

        if self.head == None:

            self.head = new_node
            self.tail = new_node
        else:
            self.tail.set_next(new_node)
            self.tail = new_node
```

Comment: The last 6 lines don't make any sense. What are you expecting head and tail to look like?

Comment: I think you should use the Node class as provided in the example code for your language. The test code seems to rely on the existence of certain attributes, like `node.next`

Comment: Where is the Insert function? Where are you returning the head of the linked list as required?

Comment: The very first line of your program should be `def Insert(node, data):`, no `class Node` and certainly no `class LL`, and that function should _return_ something.

Comment: It is impossible to provide a solution, even to a simple problem, without understanding what is being required. Hackerrank is supposed to evaluate that and you are failing to "return the head of the list in the below (Insert) method"

Comment: You also changed the given Node definition. Keep that as is and just implement the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getters and setters in python are redundant. Also, you're seriously overcomplicating things.

There are only two cases you need to worry about; The general case, and the corner case when `head` is `None`.

**Solution 1**
*Iteration*

```
def Insert(head, data):
    # handle the corner case
    if not head:
        return Node(data)

    # handle the general case
    temp = head
    while temp.next:
        temp = temp.next
    temp.next = Node(data)

    return head
```

---

**Solution 2**
*Recursion*

```
def Insert(head, data):
    if not head:
        return Node(data)

    head.next = Insert(head.next, data)
    return head
```

Both these solutions pass all test cases on Hackerrank.

Comment: thank you for answering. Actually I've tried in this way after seeing the discussion. But, may be my theoritical knowledge makes me confused! How, I can traverse the list if I write my code in IDLE in this way?

Comment: @carl Stick to the Node definition in the problem. Start from there. This code works for the skeleton code in Hackerrank. Understand what it is doing first, and then play around with it once you fully understand what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

In your code `self.tail.set_next(new_node)` is showing error because `set_next` is function of class `Node` you can access this function by `Node object`

TryThis

```
class Node:

   def __init__(self,data,nextNode=None):
       self.data = data
       self.nextNode = nextNode

   def getData(self):
       return self.data

   def setData(self,val):
       self.data = val

   def getNextNode(self):
       return self.nextNode

   def setNextNode(self,val):
       self.nextNode = val

class LinkedList:

   def __init__(self,head = None):
       self.head = head
       self.size = 0

   def getSize(self):
       return self.size

   def addNode(self,data):
       newNode = Node(data,self.head)
       self.head = newNode
       self.size+=1
       return True

   def printNode(self):
       curr = self.head
       while curr:
           print(curr.data)
           curr = curr.getNextNode()

myList = LinkedList()
print("Inserting")
print(myList.addNode(5))
print(myList.addNode(15))
print(myList.addNode(25))
print("Printing")
myList.printNode()
print("Size")
print(myList.getSize())
```

Its data structure is looks like
[image]